# 事に at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, manga

What does 事に at the end of a sentence mean? Is it 事になる？ or ことにする？ or is there just 事に that has an entirely different meaning?[image]

Comment: It's not at the end of a sentence...

Answer (score 8):

事に is not placed at the end of the sentence. The full sentence is

> あまり物騒な事に首**を**突っ込んだらダメよ

[XXXに首を突っ込む](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A6%96%E3%82%92%E7%AA%81%E3%81%A3%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80) is a set phrase. It means "to meddle into something." It is almost equivalent to English's "poke your nose into something that is none of your business."

You can understand the sentence as

> It's bad to excessively poke your nose into dangerous things.